# Azure: Pipeline bootup graph

Tags: azure-pipelines

**Background:**
In my current project, we are using Azure and the pipelines to build and test our SW.
From our build and tests we get a lot of statistics, for example: Memory usage, CPU load,
bootup times. This information is written to separate text files for each build/test.

**Question:**
Is it possible to extract this information from the artifacts/text files, and show it in a graph in the dashboard somehow?

I have searched the available widgets in my project, but all widgets can only show information about the backlog, sprints and the result from the pipeline.

For Jenkins there are several plugins that makes this possible:
[Memory map plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/memory-map/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no such option to extract build pipeline result information into dashboard. And so far, dashboard does not support this.

**As a suggestion**, you should [suggest a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) to the Team and wait for their response.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will take a look at your link!